# node - get a deeper property out of object

Tags: node.js, object

I have many objects. The objects have different properties. To retrieve the required data, I have the path to it. My question: Is it possible to work with a property path?

example object:

```
{ xy: 
  { item: [ 
            { z: { type: '1', id: 'myId', label: 'd', unit: 'dd', value: '11.20' }
          ] 
  } 
}
```

property path:

```
let path = "xy.item[0].z.value"
```

I tried following (which does not work):

```
objectName[path]
```

It works only for one propertyName but not for a "chain". Is there a simple solution to get the required data out of an object with a predefined path?

Comment: Why do you have to 'path' it? Can't you use a find or a filter to get your desired result?

Comment: Thats called "dot notation" and there exists modules to work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, json obj is not valid. you are missing a closing curly bracket.

here i have build a function that can return value from the nested object based on path you define in a string. The function can handle nested objects with arrays and subarrays. for example, path like "xy.item[0][0].z.value"

```
const obj = {
  xy: {
    item: [
      {
        z: { type: "1", id: "myId", label: "d", unit: "dd", value: "11.20" },
      },
    ],
  },
};

let path = "xy.item[0].z.value";

function findNestedValue(obj, path) {
  path_nodes = path.split(".");

  let val = obj; // value is set to the whole object value in the beginging
  for (let node of path_nodes) {
    let array_indexes = node.match(RegExp(/\[(\w)*\]/g));
    if (array_indexes) {
      //  trying to access array
      // get the array
      let key = node.slice(0, node.indexOf("["));
      val = val[key]; // now value is the array
      for (let index of array_indexes) {
        val = val[index.slice(1, index.length - 1)];
      }
    } else {
      //it is trying to access property
      val = val[node];
    }
  }
  return val;
}

console.log(findNestedValue(obj, path));
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Lodash. You can use lodash's _.get() function to get the value from any path.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let objectName = { xy: { item: [ { z: { type: '1', id: 'myId', label: 'd', unit: 'dd', value: '11.20' } } ] } };
let path = "xy.item[0].z.value";

console.log(_.get(objectName, path));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including an entire new dependency, you can just implement a function that parses the string.

Something like this should suffice, it might be a bit buggy since I've not properly tested it, otherwise it should be a good starting ground to achieve what you want without adding adding another few MB to your project.

```js
let objectName = { xy: { item: [ { z: { type: '1', id: 'myId', label: 'd', unit: 'dd', value: '11.20' } } ] } };
let x = "xy.item[0].z.value";

function parsePath(toParse, obj) {
    const parts = toParse.split('.');

    let current = obj;

    for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        const currentPart = parts[i];
        const indecies = currentPart.split('[')
        for (let j = 0; j < indecies.length; j++) {
            let currentIndex = indecies[j];
            if (currentIndex.endsWith(']')) {
                currentIndex = Number.parseFloat(currentIndex.replace(']', ''))
            }
            current = current[currentIndex]
        }
    }

    return current
}

parsePath(x, objectName) // Returns '11.20' as expected
```

The above code will not support string indices (i.e. xy["item"]) but that should be that hard to implement.